# Sharing a case in a switch statement. Expression issues. How does it work?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, expression

On an example I am working on, I have code to pick out the vowels between 'a' to 'z'. It is using a switch statement that instead of separate cases, the character values are sharing the same case. From what I know so far, the expression involved i.e

```
***(letter * (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z'))***
```

evaluates to true or false and is converted to an integer (1 and 0) in which it falls through to "case 0:" (0 obviously being false) to deal with the result should it be false. Can anyone explain the expression to conversion process involved with this statement? particularly the reasoning behind the multiplication of the logical expression. Here is my example code:

```
char letter(0); 
cout << endl
     << "Enter a small letter: ";
 cin >> letter;

switch(letter * (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z'))
{
case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
    cout << endl << "You entered a vowel.";
    break;

case 0:
        cout << endl << "That is not a small letter.";
        break;

    default: cout << endl << "You entered a consonant.";
}
```

**EDIT: All great answers guys. Cleared a lot up. Thanks again for your input**

Comment: The others have explained it.  However, whoever coded it should be taken out and shot.

Comment: @HotLicks ha ha everyone gave great answers. Just trying to decide who's answer to accept. The person that wrote the code was Ivor Horton. Up until this point I had actually never seen a switch statement used this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
letter * (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z')
```

The conditional expression multiplicand will evaluate to a true or false. The ASCII value of `letter` will be compared to the characters "a" and "z". True and false can be implicitly-converted to the numerals 1 and 0 respectively (and `letter` will be converted to its numeric ASCII value). So it will either be:

```
letter * (0)
```

or

```
letter * (1)
```

Anything times 0 is 0 which means without a corresponding case the control will go down to the default case (this one goes down to the `case: 0` part).  Otherwise, `letter * (1)` is `letter`, and therefore it will be compared by the other cases as if it were `switch (letter)`.

Answer (score 1):

`(letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z')` is a boolean expression, which evaluates to `true` if the letter is between `'a'` and `'z'`; now, when you multiply it by `letter`, it first gets promoted to `char`, assuming the value `1` if it's `true`, 0 if `false`.

Thus, the whole expression will yield `0` if the condition in the parentheses evaluates to `false`, or `letter` if it evaluates to `true`, since any `letter` multiplied by zero yields zero, and multiplied by 1 yields itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
(letter * (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z'))
```

Lets take it in 2 parts.

```
(letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z')
```

This one is easy. Is the ascii code of `letter` greater than that of `a` **and** less than that of `z`. Since letters are sequencially increasing in ascii, this means that the letter is a small letter. However the result of this expression is a `true/false`, which translates to 1/0 in the next stage.

```
(letter * <1/0>)
```

At this stage, `letter * 1` returns letter and `letter * 0` returns `0`. Which explains how the case statements work.

For the exact same reason that brought you here (lack of readability), I would split this off into a `if` first which checks for lower case letter, before passing on to the `switch`.